# How many Rak'at is it after Isha (Shia)?

Tags: salat, fiqh, shiism

Bismillahir Rahmanir Rahim. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidina wa Azimina, Wa Habibi Qulubina wa Shafii Nufusina, Abul Qasim Muhammad. Wa 'ala Ahli Bayti tayyibina tahireen.

---

[Hadith (Al Kafi V 3 – The Book Of Salāt CH 84 H 2) from kitab Al-Kafi](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/AlKafiVol3/AlKafiV3-TheBookOfSalat(6).pdf)

> (It has been narrated) from Abu Abdullah (asws) having said:
>
> ‘The Obligatory and the optional (Salāts) are fifty one Rak’at –
> **from it are two Rak’at after the night (to be prayed) seated, counted as one Rak’at prayed while he is standing.** The Obligatory
> from these are seventeen Rak’at, and the optional are thirty four
> Rak’at’.

Arabic text is

[image]

I didn't understand the description in bold. Translation is terrible. And I don't understand Arabic either.

**How many Rak'at is it after Isha?**

Can anyone explain how is it prayed and how the number of rak'ats are counted based on how it is prayed?

Answer (score 0):

In these optional prayers you have the option to do them standing or sitting.
If you choose to do one of them sitting then you have to do 2 Rak'at for each one that you would have done standing.

This one in particular (the one after Isha) you do while sitting.
So you do two but they are counted as one.

That is why the total sum of Rak'at of the optional prayers is 34.
Because the two, done sitting after Isha, are counted as one and one done in the night (the Witr) is one.